# Crear un data frame de una lista de listas en Python

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo la lista de listas:

```
   test = [('S0004-06142005000500011-1',
          [['E11.9', 'Diabetes Mellitus tipo II'],
           ['F10.20', 'enolismo'],
           ['F17.210', 'fumador'],
           ['', 'pseudodiverticulosis ureteral'],
           ['C07', 'carcinoma']]),
         ('S0004-06142005000900014-1', [['', 'leiomioma vesical']]),
         ('S0004-06142006000500012-1',
          [['', 'neoplasia oculta'],
           ['I82.90', 'trombosis'],
           ['C78.1', 'metástasis'],
           ['C64.9', 'carcinoma de células renales']])]
```

Y quiero obtener un data frame de esta forma:

```
    Archivo                     CEI10   Antecedente
0   S0004-06142005000500011-1   E11.9   Diabetes Mellitus tipo II
1   S0004-06142005000500011-1   F10.20  enolismo
2   S0004-06142005000500011-1   F17.210 fumador
3   S0004-06142005000500011-1           pseudodiverticulosis ureteral
4   S0004-06142005000500011-1   C07     carcinoma
5   S0004-06142005000900014-1           leiomioma vesical
6   S0004-06142006000500012-1           neoplasia oculta
7   S0004-06142006000500012-1   I82.90  trombosis
8   S0004-06142006000500012-1   C78.1   metástasis
9   S0004-06142006000500012-1   C64.9   carcinoma de células renales
```

Si utilizo `df = pd.DataFrame(test)` no consigo el resultado esperado pues el dataframe queda:

```
                  0                         1
0   S0004-06142005000500011-1   [[E11.9, Diabetes Mellitus tipo II], [F10.20, enolismo...
1   S0004-06142005000900014-1   [[, leiomioma vesical]]
2   S0004-06142006000500012-1   [[, neoplasia oculta], [I82.90, trombosis...
```

¿Me pueden ayudar a conseguir el data frame esperado?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder usar `pd.DataFrame()`, hay que convertir tu lista a este otro formato:

```
[['S0004-06142005000500011-1', 'E11.9', 'Diabetes Mellitus tipo II'],
 ['S0004-06142005000500011-1', 'F10.20', 'enolismo'],
 ['S0004-06142005000500011-1', 'F17.210', 'fumador'],
 ['S0004-06142005000500011-1', '', 'pseudodiverticulosis ureteral'],
 ['S0004-06142005000500011-1', 'C07', 'carcinoma'],
 ['S0004-06142005000900014-1', '', 'leiomioma vesical'],
 ['S0004-06142006000500012-1', '', 'neoplasia oculta'],
 ['S0004-06142006000500012-1', 'I82.90', 'trombosis'],
 ['S0004-06142006000500012-1', 'C78.1', 'metástasis'],
 ['S0004-06142006000500012-1', 'C64.9', 'carcinoma de células renales']]
```

Esto puede hacerse con una línea, aunque de sintaxis un tanto farragosa (que explico en el anexo):

```
from itertools import product

test = [[arc, *lst] for archivo, lista in test for arc, lst in product([archivo], lista)]
```

Una vez la has convertido, crear el DataFrame ya es trivial:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(test)
df.columns = ["Archivo", "CEI10", "Antecedente"]
```

Y el resultado es:

```
                     Archivo    CEI10                    Antecedente
0  S0004-06142005000500011-1    E11.9      Diabetes Mellitus tipo II
1  S0004-06142005000500011-1   F10.20                       enolismo
2  S0004-06142005000500011-1  F17.210                        fumador
3  S0004-06142005000500011-1           pseudodiverticulosis ureteral
4  S0004-06142005000500011-1      C07                      carcinoma
5  S0004-06142005000900014-1                       leiomioma vesical
6  S0004-06142006000500012-1                        neoplasia oculta
7  S0004-06142006000500012-1   I82.90                      trombosis
8  S0004-06142006000500012-1    C78.1                     metástasis
9  S0004-06142006000500012-1    C64.9   carcinoma de células renales
```

### Anexo

Explicación de la comprensión de listas.

Cada elemento de tu lista está formado por dos elementos:

1. El primero es el archivo, algo del estilo 'S0004-06142005000500011-1'
2. El segundo es una lista de listas, asociada con ese archivo.

Así que si iteramos `for archivo, lista in test` vamos obteniendo de forma separada esos dos elementos.

Se trata seguidamente de crear a partir de ellos otra lista "expandida" en la que el primer elemento (archivo) se repita delante de cada uno de los elementos de la otra lista. Esto lo hace `product([archivo], lista)`. La función `product` fue importada de itertools.

Pero aquí no acaba la cosa, porque ese producto daría algo como:

```
[['S0004-06142005000500011-1', ['E11.9', 'Diabetes Mellitus tipo II']],
 ['S0004-06142005000500011-1', ['F10.20', 'enolismo']],
 ['S0004-06142005000500011-1', ['F17.210', 'fumador']],
 ...
]
```

Es decir, cada elemento de la lista resultante sería una lista con dos elementos, el segundo de los cuales sería otra sublista. No queremos ese nivel de anidamiento extra, sino todo "plano".

Por eso separamos cada elemento de esta lista resultante de nuevo en dos, `arc` y `lst` y formamos con ellos una sola lista "plana" usando `[arc, *lst]` (el asterisco "expande" la lista en sus elementos, eliminando ese nivel de anidamiento)

### Otra forma

No hay por qué obsesionarse tampoco por hacerlo todo con comprensiones de listas en una sola línea (y me lo digo a mí mismo). En ocasiones un clásico bucle puede ser más claro, y además en este caso usar `itertools.product()` puede ser innecesario. Otra forma de obtener la lista apropiada para `pd.DataFrame()` podría ser la siguiente:

```
result = []
for archivo, lista in test:
  for caso in lista:
    result.append([archivo, *caso])
```

La eliminación de `itertools.product()` también puede simplificar la versión de una sola línea:

```
test = [[archivo, *caso] for archivo, lista in test for caso in lista]
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @abulafia, esto era lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: @RobertoGarrido No hay de qué. Si la pregunta está resuelta puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada, para cerrar el tema.